# Making fields clear on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Why this plugin does not work? Firebug does not notice any mistakes.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.clearForm = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).on("focus", function () {
                $(this).val() = '';
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

And in html

```
<script>
$(this).clearForm();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use  `$(this).val('')` instread of  `$(this).val()='';` 
try this

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.clearForm = function (){          
            $(this).on("focus",function(){
                $(this).val('');
            });            
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Hi. Mohit thanks, but please explain why it works only with document.ready function? I though that there is no need to include that in html file if I have plugin? thanks

Comment: To be realistic, document.ready is not needed for anything else than manipulating the DOM accurately and it's not always needed or the best option. What I mean is that when you develop a large jQuery plugin for example you hardly use it throughout the code because you're trying to keep it DRY, so you abstract as much as possible in methods that manipulate the DOM but are meant to be invoked later on. When all your code is tightly integrated the only method exposed in document.ready is usually init where all the DOM magic happens. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: you can also use
$(function(){
           $('input[type=text]').clearForm();
});
if you dont want 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type=text]').clearForm();
});